# How can I point to an internal anchor using core menu?

Tags: 7, routes

We have a navigation menu created using Drupal's built-in menu system. One of our menu items has the path set to "node/100770#digital-anchor," but when the menu is rendered, it strips off everything to the right of the node ID. [I've tried this suggestion](http://drupal.org/node/106821) (using a named id), but the issue isn't that the browser is ignoring everything the node id; it's that Drupal is actually stripping off everything after the id when the menu is rendered. If I look at the rendered source in the browser, it just isn't there.

How can we point to an internal anchor (or named element, if you believe that anchors are deprecated) using the default menu?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that through the UI.

However, you should be able to specifify it with [menu_link_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) in a module, for example in a hook_install() implementation. See the options key.

Looking at [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/7), something like `'fragment' => 'digital-anchor'` should do the trick.

Comment: I should have added that I'm extremely new to Drupal! I have no idea where I would do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6) function built into core.
The function is `l($text, $path, $options = array())`; in that options array you can specify an associative array of HTML attributes to apply to the anchor tag (the array index is "attributes").

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this before. I think it is to do with [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/759808), in the end I had to create some of my own theme functions to allow it.